# What should I pass as lpszServerName in InternetConnect?

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, download, delphi-xe7

I want to download a file from web. But I don't understand exactly what should I pass as lpszServerName parameter in [InternetConnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384363(v=vs.85).aspx).

The documentation says that I need to pass a "string that specifies the host name of an Internet server. Alternately, the string can contain the IP number of the site".

My question is: Do I need to put http and/or www in the server name or not?
I used to use only the domain name (like microsoft.com) but [I discovered a site](https://superuser.com/questions/1289758/error-accessing-a-website-when-the-url-does-not-contain-www) that won't work without 'www'.

Comment: The answer in the link clearly shows that that server was not configured properly. ISTM that normally, there should be no `www.`, but why don't you try both, in your code? If the first (no `www.`) doesn't work, try the second. If that doesn't work either, you're out of luck.

Comment: There is no way to tell if the attempt worked or not. The server returns indeed an error msg (INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND) but in my case, I don't get it because my ISP will take this message and convert it to a valid HTML page full of advertisement (I think the technical term is a 'squid').

Comment: The second problem is that some websites will not work if I force 'www'. Some (corporate/academia) web sites will have two 'entry points'. If you use www.someCorporation.com you get the 'for general public' web site. If you use just 'someCorporation.com' you get the 'for employee only' (login page) web site.